# Socket connection in CF 3.5 C#

Tags: c#, sockets, compact-framework, windows-ce

I am trying to establish a communication between a handheld and a PC.

I have the following code, for the *client*:

```
    public void connect(string IPAddress, int port)
    {
                // Connect to a remote device.
        try
        {
           IPAddress ipAddress = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192, 168, 1, 10 });
           IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
           // Create a TCP/IP socket.
           client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
           // Connect to the remote endpoint.
           client.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
           if (connectDone.WaitOne()){
                 //do something..
           }
           else{
                 MessageBox.Show("TIMEOUT on WaitOne");
           }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
                 MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
      }
```

My problem is that when I run both of them in a pc they communicate fine, but the same code in a SmartDevice Project doesn't connect with the Server which is running on the PC and it give me this error:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or stablished connection failed 
because connected host has failed to respond
```

What am I missing?

NOTE: The IPAddress is hard coded inside the code

---

**EDIT**: here is another code which I take [from a MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397809.aspx). This don't work either, it says that it not possible to read. The server code in this case is the same as the example, the client code have a modification:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // In this code example, use a hard-coded
    // IP address and message.
    string serverIP = "192.168.1.10";//HERE IS THE DIFERENCE
    string message = "Hello";
    Connect(serverIP, message);
}
```

---

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I don't see many people using the [IPAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t4k07yby.aspx) constructors, so I suspect that. Have you tried the static method `IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.10");`?

Comment: @jp2code I can`t use ´Parse´ in my CF. Any other idea? Thanks

Comment: Ew. What version CF are you on?

Comment: Looks like the connection the client on the mobile device is being refused by the server. This has nothing to do with .NET CF and everything to do with a broken server code and/or the mobile device does not actually have a network connection.

Comment: @jp2code CF 3.5. If I try to IPAddress.Parse it don't let me.

Comment: Can you use alternate versions of IPEndpoint? See [Creating an IPEndPoint from a hostname](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101777). But Ramhound may be onto something, too!

Comment: @Ramhound I am connected through GPRS so I think the network connection is fine. Regarding the Server code, if it works when I run the Client in the PC then it shouldn't be broken, don't it?

Comment: If you are connected through GPRS, then you should be using a public IP Address. `192.168.x.x` is private. Try pinging this GPRS server by the server name (i.e. GPRSServer, www.yahoo.com, etc.), and use the IP Address returned by the ping to connect.

Comment: @jp2code That should be the problem. But if I ping the handheld from the PC it receive all the packages. Which IP should I use in my client code then?

Comment: See if you can ping the PC from the mobile device using the [Windows Mobile Ping Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19484). Is "client" the PC?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14424/discussion-between-nachogsiri-and-jp2code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my "mobile device" client, I send data to the "PC" host using this:

```
private void Send(string value) {
  byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
  try {
    using (TcpClient client = new TcpClient(txtIPAddress.Text, 8000)) {
      NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
      stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }
  } catch (Exception err) {
    // Log the error
  }
}
```

For the host, you're best to use a thread or [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) where you can let a [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx) object sit and wait:

```
private void Worker_TcpListener(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
  BackgroundWorker worker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;
  do {
    string eMsg = null;
    int port = 8000;
    try {
      _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
      _listener.Start();
      TcpClient client = _listener.AcceptTcpClient(); // waits until data is avaiable
      int MAX = client.ReceiveBufferSize;
      NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
      Byte[] buffer = new Byte[MAX];
      int len = stream.Read(buffer, 0, MAX);
      if (0 < len) {
        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        worker.ReportProgress(len, data.Substring(0, len));
      }
      stream.Close();
      client.Close();
    } catch (Exception err) {
      // Log your error
    }
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(eMsg)) {
      worker.ReportProgress(0, eMsg);
    }
  } while (!worker.CancellationPending);
}
```

Comment: I have a code pretty similar to yours taken from a MDSN example. I'm going to update my question with that code so you can check it.